# Smooth linear interpolation using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-interpolation

I need to recode an equivalent of the NumPy [`interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html#numpy-interp) function. In order to do that, I thought of building a pairwise distance matrix, and then using this matrix to define "weights" that I use to multiply the target values.

```py
def interp_diff(x, xp, fp):
    dxp = np.diff(xp)
    dxp = np.concatenate(([dxp[0]], dxp))

    pairwise_distance = np.abs(x[:, np.newaxis] - xp)  # Calculate the absolute differences between x and xp

    # Add a small epsilon to pairwise distances to avoid division by zero
    epsilon = 1e-8
    pairwise_distance += epsilon

    weights = 1 / pairwise_distance  # Calculate the weights based on the differences

    # Normalize the weights
    weights /= np.sum(weights, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

    # Apply hardness threshold to the weights
    weights = np.where(weights > 0, weights, 0)

    return np.dot(weights, fp)
```

This produces expected results when xp values are placed on a regular grid, but it does not work if xp values are not evenly spaced. How can I make this work for any spacing of xp?

The constraint I have is that **I can't use index related methods (argsort, argwhere, searchsorted, etc...)**. Which is what makes it a bit challenging.

Example usage on a regular grid:

```py
x_np = np.linspace(0, 5, 4)
y_np = np.sin(x_np)
x_i = x_np
x_i = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y_i = interp_diff(x_i, xp=x_np, fp=y_np)
ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_np, y_np)
ax.scatter(x_i, y_i, marker='+', s=30, alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(x_i, y_i)
plt.show()
```

Produces the expected result:

[image]

However, switching to non evenly spaced grid:

```py
def sinspace(start, stop, num):

    ones = 0 * start + 1
    return start + (stop - start) * (1 - np.cos(np.linspace(
        0 * ones,
        np.pi / 2 * ones,
        num
    )))
x_np = sinspace(0, 5, 4)
y_np = np.sin(x_np)
x_i = x_np
x_i = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y_i = interp_diff(x_i, xp=x_np, fp=y_np)
ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_np, y_np)
ax.scatter(x_i, y_i, marker='+', s=30, alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(x_i, y_i)
plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: The constraint of not use index related methods is hard to bypass, idk if it's even doable, maybe working on why you can't use index related methods can be a idea. if you can explain why, I would love to think about it.

Comment: Explaining why it quite long and I amnot sure it is necessary to answer the question. In short, I am using an adaptation of numpy library (casadi.org) that is used in an automatic differentiation context - that does not support index related methods. So in order to be able to perform linear interpolation in this context, I need to find a way with the remaining equivalent numpy functions I have. I am asking the questions with numpy because it's a well known library (this is not the case of casadi, but they share a lot of common functions)

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to produce the output you say it does. Specifically where you say "produces expected result". It doesn't.

Comment: I see strange extra code. 1. The `dxp` variable in interp_diff is unused. 2. In the regular grid example you have `x_i = x_np` immediately followed by another assignment to the same variable. As far as I can tell both examples are code that does nothing. Should they be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate your results with a slightly modified version of the code you supplied:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

def interp_diff(x, xp, fp):
    dxp = numpy.diff(xp)
    dxp = numpy.concatenate(([dxp[0]], dxp))

    pairwise_distance = numpy.abs(x[:, numpy.newaxis] - xp)  # Calculate the absolute differences between x and xp

    # Add a small epsilon to pairwise distances to avoid division by zero
    epsilon = 1e-8
    pairwise_distance += epsilon

    weights = 1 / pairwise_distance  # Calculate the weights based on the differences

    # Normalize the weights
    weights /= numpy.sum(weights, axis=1)[:, numpy.newaxis]

    # Apply hardness threshold to the weights
    weights = numpy.where(weights > 0, weights, 0)

    return numpy.dot(weights, fp)

# 1 : 1 grid
x_np = numpy.linspace(0,5,4)
y_np = numpy.sin(x_np)
x_i = x_np
y_i = interp_diff(x_i,xp=x_np,fp=y_np)
ax = pyplot.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_np,y_np)
ax.scatter(x_i,y_i,marker='+',s=30,alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(x_i,y_i)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Evenly spaced grid plot]

```
# 1 : 2.5 grid
x_np = numpy.linspace(0,5,4)
y_np = numpy.sin(x_np)
x_i = numpy.linspace(0,5,10)
y_i = interp_diff(x_i,xp=x_np,fp=y_np)
ax = pyplot.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_np,y_np)
ax.scatter(x_i,y_i,marker='+',s=30,alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(x_i,y_i)
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Unevenly spaced grid plot]

Which version of the `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries are you using?

Comment: This is because you use a regular grid in both cases. I just edited and added the code for non evenly space grid

Answer (score 0):

The `interp_diff` function to work with unevenly spaced `xp` values, i have chnaged with `np.subtract.outer` function to calculate the pairwise differences between `x` and `xp` without relying on index-related methods.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def interp_diff(x, xp, fp):
    dxp = np.diff(xp)
    dxp = np.concatenate(([dxp[0]], dxp))

pairwise_distance = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x, xp))  # Calculate the absolute differences between x and xp

# Add a small epsilon to pairwise distances to avoid division by zero
epsilon = 1e-8
pairwise_distance += epsilon

weights = 1 / pairwise_distance  # Calculate the weights based on the differences

# Normalize weights
weights /= np.sum(weights, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

# Apply hardness threshold to the weights
weights = np.where(weights > 0, weights, 0)

return np.dot(weights, fp)

x_np = np.linspace(0, 5, 4)
y_np = np.sin(x_np)
x_i = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y_i = interp_diff(x_i, xp=x_np, fp=y_np)

ax = plt.figure().gca()
ax.scatter(x_np, y_np)
ax.scatter(x_i, y_i, marker='+', s=30, alpha=0.7)
ax.plot(x_i, y_i)
plt.show()
```

[image: output image:]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will do exactly what you want, since it uses a few boolean arrays which may cause problems with your gradients. But it produces the correct result (comparing to Numpy) and doesn't use any complicated indexing:

```py
def interp_diff(x, xp, fp):
    diff_filter = np.diff(x[:, np.newaxis] >= xp, axis=-1)
    prev_filter = np.concatenate((diff_filter, ~np.any(
        diff_filter, axis=-1, keepdims=True)), axis=-1)
    next_filter = np.concatenate(
        (np.broadcast_to(False, (diff_filter.shape[0], 1)), diff_filter), axis=-1)

    epsilon = 1e-8
    pairwise_distance = xp - x[:, np.newaxis]
    prev_dist = np.where(prev_filter, -pairwise_distance, 0)
    next_dist = np.where(next_filter, pairwise_distance, 0)
    progress = prev_dist / \
        ((prev_dist + next_dist).sum(axis=-1) + epsilon)[..., np.newaxis]

    return np.sum(np.where(prev_filter, fp, 0) + np.concatenate((np.diff(fp), [0])) * progress, axis=-1)
```

It works by abusing `np.diff` on boolean arrays to get the previous and the subsequent point in `xp`. It then calculates how far between the two points the new point is and uses `np.diff` again to offset the new point from the previous closest point.

[image: Output of interp_diff function on sample data]